# Is it possible to have permanent rain?

Tags: hard-science, weather

Let's say there's a land-based location called Verywet on a fictional world. Assuming this fictional world follows the same laws of nature that our own planet does, would it be possible for it to continually rain over Verywet? By continual, I mean that while the intensity of the rain may be lighter or heavier at times, there is never a moment when drops are not falling from the sky.

If it is feasible what sort of environment would be required? Would the rainfall need a lot of water beneath it? Or would it need to be near a coast that brought a constant supply of storms inward?

If it is impossible for an Earth-like world, what would be needed to make it work? Other than magic.

Comment: [Also related.](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/14300/how-can-i-explain-a-planet-with-perpetual-rain?rq=1) Neither question uses the [tag:hard-science] tag, though, so that might be enough to differentiate them.

Comment: They actually are quite similar, though I would definitely appreciate a more "hard-science" answer if possible.

Comment: Seattle gets pretty darn close.

Comment: A tidally locked planet orbiting a Red Dwarf star might have permanent rainy zones since the atmosphere will be circulating in fixed cells.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Never** is a word that is remarkably hard to use with weather.  The answer is almost always "no" because there's always a statistical chance of unusual weather occurring.  However, for all intents and purposes, there's no reason not to assume a region is arbitrarily rainy.  All it needs is to be part of a Coriolis cell which collects a lot of moisture, and then have a giant mountain peak to encourage as much of it to condense as possible.

The [Guiness Book of World Records](http://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/world-records/most-rainy-days/) demonstrates that lots of rain does happen:

> Most rainy days - world
>   Mt Wai-`ale-`ale (1569m 5148ft), Kauai, Hawaii has up to 350 rainy days per annum.

Answer (score 0):

Supposedly a Flash Gordon episode said "it rained on planet Mongo." I never checked it, but it sounds good enough that it [should](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SingleBiomePlanet) be true.

I think you can build a world where **one region** gets almost constant rain. Shape your continents to create [rain shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rain_shadow) in the [oceanic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oceanic_climate) climate zone.